# norm of differences of variables in cvxpy

Tags: python, cvxpy

How can I take the following norm in `cvxpy`

[image]

```
sum(norm(x[i] - x[j], p=2), i=1, j>i, i, j = n)
```

where `x` is `(n, 2)` variable matrix defined by `x = cp.Variable((n, 2))`. For the problem, I am taking n=16. The following is the code I am trying to completely

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp


def solver(pts, var, lmb):
    objective = cp.Minimize(cp.norm(pts - var, 2) + cp.norm(var, 2))
    prob = cp.Problem(objective)
    prob.solve()
    print(prob.value)
    return np.round(var.value, 2)

pts = np.array([(-2, 3), (-3, 5), (-1, 4), (-3, 7) , (0, 3), 
                (-2, -2), (-3, 8), (3, 1), (1, -2), (2, 6), 
                (-2, 6), (-2, 5), (-4, 3), (-4, 6), (-3, 10), 
                (2, -3)])

n = pts.shape[0]
var = cp.Variable((n, 2))

solver(pts, var, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved exactly because you don't have any constraint.
I skipped the function to make you a shorter script.

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
pts = np.array([(-2, 3), (-3, 5), (-1, 4), (-3, 7), (0, 3),
                (-2, -2), (-3, 8), (3, 1), (1, -2), (2, 6),
                (-2, 6), (-2, 5), (-4, 3), (-4, 6), (-3, 10),
                (2, -3)])

n = pts.shape[0]
x = cp.Variable((n, 2))
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.norm(pts - x, 2, axis=1)))
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
prob.solve()

print(x.value)
# result
# [[-2.  3.]
#  [-3.  5.]
#  [-1.  4.]
#  [-3.  7.]
#  [ 0.  3.]
#  [-2. -2.]
#  [-3.  8.]
#  [ 3.  1.]
#  [ 1. -2.]
#  [ 2.  6.]
#  [-2.  6.]
#  [-2.  5.]
#  [-4.  3.]
#  [-4.  6.]
#  [-3. 10.]
#  [ 2. -3.]]
```

P.S. maybe this is not your correct answer. The problem is that from what I see in your equation. I'm not able to differentiate the parameters and your values.

[image]

Does it mean that you have two functions to minimize? one approaching the points and the other one approaching all the previous points to the current one?

If that's the case, you can replace the code with:

```
cost1 = cp.sum(cp.norm(pts - x, 2, axis=1))
cost2 = cp.sum([cp.norm(x[j] - x[i],2) for i in range(1, n) for j in range(0, i)])
objective = cp.Minimize(cost1+cost2)
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
prob.solve()
print(x.value)
#result
# [[-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]
#  [-1.7909687  4.4720621]]
```

But as you can see, the result is not that interesting.

Comment: lemme try, it might work